# ASP.NET and SQL Adding value of two table cell in a row and saved in third cell of the row

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

My question is very simple, I have a table with four columns and those are:

```
ID int

value01 int

value02 int

total int
```

In the asp.net page the user will insert in a textbox the value of value01 and value02 and automatically the total will add the value of both of those columns without the need of a user doing anything.

Also the table will have multiple rows therefore the total of one row should be the `value01` and `value02` addition of that current row ?

Comment: Can you show me some example ?

Comment: dont ask us to code for you,show us what you have tried,sure we will help you.

Comment: There is no code Cz I have no idea how to implement this, I want somebody to help me find a logic towards this. thnks for your comment

Answer (score 0):

customize below javascript to your grid

```
function sum() {
    var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('<%= txtjirayat1.ClientID %>').value;
    var txtSecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('<%= txtbagayat1.ClientID %>').value;
    var txtthirdno = document.getElementById('<%= txtpad.ClientID %>').value;
    var result = parseFloat(txtFirstNumberValue) + parseFloat(txtSecondNumberValue) + parseFloat(txtthirdno);
    if (!isNaN(result)) {
        document.getElementById('<%= txttotal.ClientID %>').value = result;

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
Update TableName Set total = value01 + value01 Where Id = @ID
```

Comment: You mean to add this code at the button when inserted?? and does the '@ID' is enough for understanding for the current row, you know since 'ID' is auto generated

Comment: @BGS that was only backend process

Comment: Whether you would like to do this using asp .net or Sql.. In asp .net code then where you want to show the total value.?

Comment: @Anand .Yes. sam tagged this question with sql so only i provide the script block

Comment: @BGS yea,but that was partial code.it was also mention to automatic add result